# protobuf-net collection in collection

Tags: c#, collections, protobuf-net, synchronize

We are using protobuf-net over a bus, to sync objects. It is working fine for objects in collections. We listen to `CollectionChanged` events and the complete objects are being synchronized and distributed on a dedicated channel on the bus. Our objects are containing lists (dictionary), they are completely being serialized/deserialized.

Until now that was not a problem, but we want to be more efficient and only send these list updates. If I set `OverwriteList = false` and I try to use the `Model.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix` method I get the following error message :

> "An item with the same key has already been added." (at
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) 
>   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue
>   value, Boolean add)    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.System.Collections.Generic.ICollection>.Add(KeyValuePair`2
>   keyValuePair)    at proto_13(Object , ProtoReader )

Can protobuf handle the changes in these collections/dictionaries for us, or should we listen to changes ourselves?

Comment: Can you give an example of the sort of time when this is occurring? And what the `CollectionChanged` events are doing here? Basically, is there something I might see that *demonstrates* this happening? That message would *suggest* that a duplicate key is being added, which we wouldn't expect to come from the source data: however, is it possible that the default constructor (or field initializer) is putting some initial values into the dictionary? If so, there are certainly ways around that.

Comment: if you are serialising just the changes and pushing that accross, is it possible that you are deserialising your changes into the existing object(that may have already recevied an update)? should you deserialise your changes into a new object then merge those with your existing?

Comment: @user1997332 I'd love to help, but there is necessary missing information that only you can provide

Comment: Let me try to elaborate a bit: assume you have one object { Guid id, List<string> Labels} that you wish to keep in sync between two applications A and B. If A adds a new label l1 to the Labels list, B needs to receive it too. We are using protobuf to serialize the object between A and B, and if we use OverwriteList=true, this works well. B's copy is adjusted appropriately. However, the Labels list becomes long, so the messages too, and we only want to send the new elements across, say label l2 (and not label l1). How can we achieve this using protobuf?

Comment: @ErikVullings that *seems* to be a different question; protobuf-net does support both conditional serialization and merge-based deserialization (putting data into an existing object). However, a concrete code-based example (simplified, ideally) would ***really*** help here. Also - it isn't clear: are you also `user1997332` ?